# How do I query two columns in CartoDB?

Tags: carto, query

I'm making a simple map with locations of daycare centers plotted. I have two filters, one that shows ages and another that shows different types of centers. I can filter one one or the other, but not both.

http://www.datanarratives.org/daycarefinder2014/

For example, how do I filter the map to show only Corporate sites that serve 0-2 years?

Currently the query for one column is like this:

```
query = "select * from table_04apr2014 where age_range like "+ "'%"+agerange+"%'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing anything about cartodb but believing it is just like all SQL databases, if you have attributes "age_range" and "type" it might be something like
"select * from table_04apr2014 where age_range like "+ "'%"+agerange+"%'" and type like "+ "'%"+typevariable+"%'";

Syntax may be wrong with all the +%'" but you seem to know how to write the query.